# Ignore types that reference a typescript library if not included in current project

Tags: typescript

In @types/urijs, there exists a type that references `HTMLElement`

```
new (value?: string | URIOptions | HTMLElement): URI;
```

Is there a way to ignore the `HTMLElement` type if I do not want to include `lib:dom` in my `tsconfig.json`?

The ideal type locally would be `string | URIOptions`

Comment: If you were to `import 'urijs'` and not add `lib:dom` to your `types`, does that not work?

Comment: It fails on compile with `node_modules/@types/urijs/index.d.ts(163,40): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a proposal to support placeholder types as described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31894). Unfortunately  it is not yet implemented

You will need to make a sort of forward declaration interface to satisfy the types in that library:

```
declare global {
   interface HTMLElement {}
}
```

Now this does mean you will have a global empty interface named `HTMLElement` which may lead to other issues, since `HTMLElement` is the empty object type (`{}`) any other type will be assignable to it.

Another option would be to declare `HTMLElement` as `never`:

```
declare global {
   type HTMLElement = never
}
```

Although this will be incompatible with modules that add augmentations for the `HTMLElement` interface.

A decent compromise might be to declare a guard property in the interface to ensure it is not compatible with other types:

```
declare global {
   interface HTMLElement {
       guard: "DO NOT INSTANTIATE"
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly the issue I was running into. Unfortunately I don't think I can use any of the approaches since I was attempting to fix type dependencies in an open source repo. They are currently using a local Github type declaration for `urijs` and I wanted to find a way to get rid of it.
Would it be fine to include this is the DefinitelyTyped definition for `urijs`? I assume that this might be a little too hacky, but I'm unsure of conventions.

Comment: @BohrHew I am sure I have seen libraries include such forward declarations. Lodash I think includes them for `Map` I belive but I am not sure how they deal with the `{} ` issue if at all.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it Lodash's implementation and see if I can submit a PR to @types/urijs

Comment: @BohrHew reading your original comment, I'm not sure I made it clear that the fixes above will work if you add them to your project. Since the types are global, they will fix any errors in package definitions

Comment: The problem was part of a bigger issue that an open source package was relying on a GitHub type definition that fails to work in some production environments that block GitHub repos. Unfortunately the fix won't work directly within my project since it fails on npm install